# How do I get a random entry's URL from a Entries field?

Tags: templating, entries, url, random

I have a Entries field and I'd like to return a URL for one randomly picked entry.

I could loop through all the entries, but I'd like to do something more efficient. Can I return an array of URLs? Or better yet, is it possible to randomly get one URL all at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to have the query pick a random entry.
From the Craft [Entries Fields](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields#templating) docs we see that `entry.entriesFieldHandle` is a shortcut for

```
craft.entries({
  relatedTo: { sourceElement: entry, field: "entriesFieldHandle" },
  order: "sortOrder",
  limit: null
})
```

And what we want is to order the entries randomly, and then limit the number we retrieve to only one:

```
craft.entries({
  relatedTo: { sourceElement: entry, field: "entriesFieldHandle" },
  order: "RAND()",
  limit: 1
})
```

So to retrieve one random entry and get its url:

```
{% set randomEntry = craft.entries({
      relatedTo: { sourceElement: entry, field: "entriesFieldHandle" },
      order: "RAND()",
      limit: 1
    }).first()
%}
{% if randomEntry %}
  {% set randomUrl = randomEntry.url %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Interesting answer, Marion! Performance is better with your second approach, right? Then I'd leave out the random() part or put it at the end of the answer.

Comment: _(Sorry for the repost, I found a big error in my old comment.)_ Very cool way to do it! Using your last example I keep getting randomEntry returning as null. All I've changed is my "field:" to "aGlobalSet.entriesField". Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: @SimonKuran to pick a random entry from `aGlobalSet` you want `{sourceElement: aGlobalSet, field: "entriesField"}`

Comment: Ah, I get it now. It worked, thanks! I put an edit in the queue adding the "all at once" technique I used to your answer.

Comment: I think the more common use case is that someone wants a random entry (with title, url, etc.), not just the url of a random entry

Comment: Oh, I'm sure it is. My example just better matched the question, but it's fairly self-explanatory to simplify down to it. It's totally fine added or not. :)

Answer (score 3):

No need to loop. You can use `random()`:

```
{% set randomEntry = random(entry.entriesFieldHandle) %}
{% if randomEntry %}
    {% set randomUrl = randomEntry.url %}
{% endif %}
```

`randomUrl` is your random entry's url you wanted to get.

Comment: [random](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/random.html) is a twig function. `random(entry.entriesFieldHandle)` will retrieve all the entries, then pick a random one.

Comment: @Marion Is anything bad in it? OP seems to ask about twig...  Sorry, not really so experienced :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Just responding to @ChristianSeelbach comment on my answer. Picking the random entry with the query is probably more efficient if there are a lot of entries, but your code is simpler. Should check that it found something though.

Comment: @Marion You mean if it found an entry? Well, why not...

Comment: @micael yes. If there are no entries, randomEntry.url will give an error

Comment: @Marion Now? :-) And I seem to be nicael, not micael :D And no need to add `@reply` if you respond to the post author - he is automatically notified.